# Set DIV to visible when hyperlink hover - CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have attached a snippet of my HTML.

Is it possible if I hover over the hyperlink with ID **li1link** that div#li1 is displayed, and if I hover over the hyperlink with ID **li2link** then div#li2 is displayed. Is this easily achievable?

So I guess the default is the DIVs are set to *display:hidden* until that particular related link is hovered over/active.

To confirm, **only one DIV will be visible at any time**.

Here is my current HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#li1" id=li1link">Test 1 - hover over to display ul#li1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#li2" id=li2link">Test 2 - hover over to display ul#li2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="li1">
    <ul>
        <li>Content 1</li>
        <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="li2">
        <ul>
            <li>Content 2</li>
            <li>Content 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm open to using jQuery or CSS, I'm just not totally sure how to approach this issue. Confused is an understatement.

Many thanks for any pointers with this.

Comment: Is the a->href is going to be same as div ID? if yes, you can use single function to handle all such cases... http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dtEEQ/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
// for all links that have link keyword in their ids
$('a[id*="link"]').mouseenter(function(){
  // get the div id out of this
  var id = this.id.replace('link', '');
  // hide all other divs
  $('div[id^="li"]').hide();
  // show the needed div now
  $('#' + id).show();
});

// hide when mouse moves away
$('a[id*="link"]').mouseout(function(){
  var id = this.id.replace('link', '');
  $('#' + id).hide();
});
```

> To confirm, only one DIV will be visible at any time.

These lines take care of that:

```
$('div[id^="li"]').hide();
// show the needed div now
$('#' + id).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, Sarfraz :-) I will give it a try right now.

Comment: Thanks again. Should I be setting my divs to display:hidden at the beginning?

Comment: @mcgarriers: The above code assumes they are hidden initially, so you can go ahead and do that.

Comment: Brilliant. It's 99% working. Only issue is when I roll "off", the last div is still "active". How do I fix this?

Comment: @mcgarriers - just to make sure - it is `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. Visibility keeps space not showing content display hides everything as if there was no content.

Comment: It works beautifully. Many, many thanks for your help and patience with this. It's very much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#li1link).hover(function(){
   $("#li1").attr('display','block');
});

$("#li1link).mouseover(function(){
   $("#li").attr('display','none');
});
```

You can do similar thing when #li2link and display #li2 and hide it.

Comment: Thanks, Ajai. I'll give it a try in a minute.

Comment: That is not a good approach, if he has 50 links and divs, he will have to repeat same code for all of those.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Agreed. I was just addressing the problem.. Since the question did not talk about generic solution I did not address it.

Comment: Hover function can take 2 arg, mousein and mouseout handlers.. Why do you need a seperate function.

Comment: @SKS: Yes it is also possible. Thought this could be more clearer to understand. The idea is in itself quite simple. Just wanted to be clear... Nothing specific for this answer..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var p = {
                onmouseover: function(link) {
                document.getElementById(link.id.substring(0, 3)).style.display = "block";
                 },
                onmouseout: function(link) {
                document.getElementById(link.id.substring(0, 3)).style.display = "none";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#li1" id=li1link" onmouseover="p.onmouseover(this)" onmouseout="p.onmouseout(this)">Test 1 - hover over to display ul#li1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#li2" id=li2link" onmouseover="p.onmouseover(this)" onmouseout="p.onmouseout(this)">Test 2 - hover over to display ul#li2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="li1" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li>Content 1</li>
                <li>Content 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="li2" style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li>Content 2</li>
                <li>Content 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I've gone for Safraz's answer above. Really appreciate you taking the time. Hopefully it'll help someone else in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

With a minor html change (adding a class to your ul) you can handle it all in 1 function,

**Assumption:** The a->href value and the div ID are same.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/dtEEQ/)

HTML Change:

```
<ul class="showDivOnHover">
    <li><a href="#li1" id=li1link">Test 1 - hover over to display ul#li1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#li2" id=li2link">Test 2 - hover over to display ul#li2</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
 $('.showDivOnHover a').hover (function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
 }, function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, SKS. I have gone for Safraz's answer above, but will look into this shortly. Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AwsSj/)

CSS:

```
#li1link, #li2link {        
    display: none;
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$("#li1, #li2").hover(
    function () {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'link').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'link').hide();
    });​
```

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery, tried to give you a quick solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/88nKd/

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" id="1" class="liLink">Test 1 - hover over to display ul#li1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2" class="liLink">Test 2 - hover over to display ul#li2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="li1" class="none">
    <ul>
        <li>Content 1</li>
        <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="li2" class="none">
    <ul>
        <li>Content 2</li>
        <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
css:
.none{
    display:none;
}
js:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".liLink").mouseover(function(){
        var linkNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        var divNumber = '#li'+linkNumber;
        $(divNumber).show();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        var linkNumber = $(this).attr('id');
        var divNumber = '#li'+linkNumber;
        $(divNumber).hide();
    });
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I find having a class which deals with the styles and then adding and removing those works well for me, so:
(Please note the below code will remove the class when not hovering over the link and I would recommend giving the links sensible class names to do the selector on rather than all a tags, same with the divs)

CSS:

```
div {
    visibility:hidden; // Or display:none; or left: -999em; depending on what your page is there for.
}
div.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JS:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('show');
  }, function() {
  $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('show');
});
```